# Mutually exclusive properties in Swagger definition

Tags: swagger

A common pattern in API design is to sometimes prefetch related entities, while at other times only provide the id of the related entity.

For example, when fetching a user you could get the related organisation:

```
{ 
   "id": "user-id",
   "organisation": {
      "id": "org-id"
   }
}
```

At other times (like in lists of users) you could get only the organisation id, in the same field.

```
{ 
   "id": "user-id",
   "organisation": "org-id"
}
```

Alternatively, you would get only the organisation id but in a differently named field:

```
{ 
   "id": "user-id",
   "organisationId": "org-id"
}
```

My question is, can we define such a variable schema in Swagger? We could of course define a `UserWithOrganisation` and a `UserWithoutOrganisation` but if we have several relations the problem gets out of hand really fast.

In the first presented case, the type of a field would need to be either a primitive or an object.

In the second case, either the `organisation` property, or the `organisationId` property is present, but never both and always one.

Comment: A workaround is to define the `organisation` and `organisationId` properties as optional but that cannot enforce the mutually exclusive constraint